# 1850s English equivalent to "Ladies and Gentlemen" for introducing an act to a working class crowd?

Tags: salutations, nineteenth-century-english, class-based-usage

I'm working on a script for a story set in 1850s London and in it my main characters visit a music hall.

I had originally been planning on including some background monologue to the effect of *"Ladies and Gentlemen, please put your hands together for..."*, but then I remembered that both "lady" and "gentleman" were still somewhat more class-specific terms in English society back then. (Also, from what I can gather, introducing a show with Ladies and Gentlemen seems to have originated as more of an American thing a little later on in history).

What would be a more period-appropriate ways for an MC to refer to a mostly working class English crowd?

Comment: Invent something: My dear friends! Also, are you sure *put your hands together* isn't recent? You can hardly use *Give it up for Matti!*

Comment: I don't know why you might think ***Ladies and gentlemen*** as a form of address started in America. The capitalisation of [this NGram chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Ladies+and+gentlemen%3Aeng_us_2019%2CLadies+and+gentlemen%3Aeng_gb_2019&year_start=1770&year_end=1880&corpus=en-US-2019&smoothing=10) means it will mostly pick up contexts where it's used to address the group collectively, and if anything it seems to have started to gain traction in BrE, not AmE. But in any case, I'm sure it was always used for *all* mixed-sex audiences, not just the nobility.

Comment: ...but it's only really an "attention-grabber" in many cases. So no different to ***Listen up!*** as often occurs in military and other contexts. You rarely *need* to directly identify your audience when you address them in English, though. As everyone who's ever forgotten the other person's name will be gratefully aware.

Comment: The OED's first cited use is **1808**   F. Grose Antiq. Rep. II. 405   *All public addresses to a mixed assembly of both sexes, till sixty years ago, commenced **Gentlemen and Ladies**: at present it is **Ladies and Gentlemen.***

Comment: @FumbleFingers I can't remember exactly where but I think I saw a reference somewhere that it's popularity as an opener to shows stemmed from Barnum and Bailey, but I guess a citation from 1808 would take precedence as a source. I'll definitely mull it over.

Comment: There seem to be lots of modern books about Victorian music hall, including novels, although not sure how trustworthy they are. A quick search doesn't turn up much in fiction from the time. I'd be more worried about whether "put your hands together" is historically accurate, as it seems more likely to change than "ladies and gentlemen" - are you interested in the whole introduction?

Comment: Why wouldn't a compère flatter the audience with "Ladies and gentlemen"? Should they delight them with "Hey you riff-raff"? Punk wasn't until late 20th century. It's all about *entertainment* and a working-class audience might have found the "L & G" funny.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ladles and jelly spoons, buoys and gulls, isn't it bordering a question of opinion?  That's entertainment.

Comment: @StuartF I mean I'm certainly keeping an eye out for other language things. I'm not necessarily aiming for 100% historical accuracy, but I want to be more authentic and contextual than just going with a broad strokes "this is how people talked back in the victorian era"/"this is how people talked in the olden days" approach solely based on my exposure to pop culture things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a long-running British TV series The Good Old Days that re-created the Music Hall experience on TV.

The emcee always said "Ladies and Gentlemen".  It's a perfectly good phrase to use.

Many episodes available on Youtube. Here's a couple.

https://youtu.be/tjibKx8LmLM?t=184

https://youtu.be/vKn_5K_KGek?t=46

Comment: So did [Lawrence Welk](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Lawrence_Welk_Show) for forty years.  Live audience musical variety show.  PBS sadly took it off the air after what, sixty years after it ran in syndication plus reruns?  Saturday night ruined here.